# Cannot find the time complexity of this C code?

Tags: c, runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having hard time trying to figure out how to calculate the time complexity of some code. I know the basics of Big O, although I can't fully understand how to calculate in general.

Here is an example to something I couldn't solve. Hopefully you can:

```
void f(int n) {
    int j, s;
    for (j = 0, s = 1; s < n; j++, s*=2)
        printf(“!”);
    double values[j];
    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
        values[k] = 0;
    while (j--)
        for (int k = 1; k < j; k++)
            values[k] += 1.0 / k;
}
```

What's the run time? I would love an explanation :)

Comment: What is the runtime, or the big-O complexity?

Comment: @juanchopanza Oh, didn't know it's two different things. Like, O(logn) or O(n^2) and this kind of calculations if it means anything to you. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A good start might be to format the code so it's more readable. In C white-space is not significant (outside of string and character literals) so things like indentation are not really important *for the compiler*. It is *very* important for humans though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My bad :) Fixed.

Comment: If you don't understand the difference between big- complexity and runtime, I doubt anyone can give an answer that is meaningful to you.    Program execution time is affected by many things, including algorithm complexity.   So I'm voting to close the thread.

Comment: Well, depending on `n`, the first loop could be infinite (e.g. `n = INT_MAX`), which would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Peter English is not my native language. I must have mixed two different things trying to translate what I meant. I'm talking about the one which you calcualte the O(x) for him. For example two for loops one in each other will be O(n^2) and so on.. You get me :)

Comment: How should I call it to prevent further confusions?

Comment: @EOF Depending on n, the answer should be O(log^2(n)) by the book.

Comment: @sadasassadsadas: Why don't you try? Call `f(INT_MAX)` and see what kind of runtime you get...

Comment: @EOF I bet it'll be just the way you describe, although this was a question in an exam I'm studying from, which means it's absolutely solveable. Do you know how to get to the answer O(log^2(n))?

Comment: You want us to help with exam revision?

Comment: @MartinJames If you can't be useful, don't post in my thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first loop iterates `log2(n)` times, computing `j`, the order of the highest bit of `n`. Complexity `O(log(n))`.

The second loop initializes an array of size `j`:  time and space complexity `O(log(n))`.

The third loop is a nested loop iterating `j` times with the nested loop iterating `j` to `1` times, for a total of `j * (j - 1) / 2` times.  The time complexity of this is `O(log(n)^2)`, and dominates the previous phases.

The overall time complexity of this function is `O(log(n)^2)`, while the space complexity is `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Finally someone useful. Much appreciated. Thank you.